# Simplify expressions by automated substitution of repeated terms

Tags: simplifying-expressions, replacement

I would like to know whether there is a way in Mathematica to simplify an expression including the introduction of symbols for repeated terms, like so:

> SimplifyWithSubstitution[(a+b)^7+(a+b)^3+(a+b)^2-a-b]

should yield

> C^7+C^3+C^2-C, C=a+b

Note that I do want Mathematica to figure out that the expression can be shortened by substituting `a+b`.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `- a - b` in the last part? Anyway: `Eliminate[{res == (a + b)^7 + (a + b)^3 + (a + b)^2 - a - b, c == a + b}, {a, b}]`

Comment: Of course there was a sign error, thanks! Your proposal requires the user to recognize that a+b is repeated and may be replaced, I want MMA to do this.

Comment: ``Experimental`OptimizeExpression[]`` gets pretty close: ``Experimental`OptimizeExpression[(a + b)^7 + (a + b)^3 + (a + b)^2 - a - b]``

Comment: Well thanks, thats what I needed!